# Cannot get search params in page.tsx | Next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I was building a next js project, using next 13 page router, I need to get the search params in from server component

```
 export default async function Home({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: {domain: string};
  searchParams: {[key: string]: string | string[] | undefined};
}) {
  const [data] = await Promise.all([getSiteData(params.domain)]);

  if (!data) {
    notFound();
  }
  console.log(searchParams);
```

the params prop is work just find when i go into domain.localhost:3000 it return 'domian'
but when I go to domain.localhost:3000/?limit=3 or any number or string , searchParams prop always return {}

Even I try searchParams.limit or searchParams['limit] , it always return 'undefined'
So what is the right way to get tbe search params from server component
thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access query parameters in a server-side component, you can do so using the context object in the getServerSideProps function. Here's an example of how you can access query parameters in a server-side component

```
// pages/somepage.js
import React from 'react';

const SomePage = ({ searchParams }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Search Params: {JSON.stringify(searchParams)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { query } = context;

  // `query` contains the query parameters
  // You can pass the query parameters as props to your component
  return {
    props: {
      searchParams: query,
    },
  };
}

export default SomePage;
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the App directory btw